# Hints of showing an identity of Lie derivative

Tags: manifolds, lie-derivative

Let $X$, $Y$ be vector fields on manifold $M$ and $f$ is a real smooth function on $M$, then may I get some hints of showing $(L_X L_Y-L_Y L_X)(f)=L_{[X,Y]}f$, where $[X,Y]$ means the Lie bracket?

Comment: Do you know the definition of  $L_X f$?

Comment: yes, it is a real smooth function on $M$ such that $L_X f(p)=df_p X(p)$.

Comment: Then do you know the definition for $df_p (X_p)$? Which is just $X_p f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution. The Lie derivative of $f \in C^\infty(M)$ with respect to $V$, which we denoted by $\mathscr{L}_V f$, is defined

> \begin{align} (\mathscr{L}_V f)_p =\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f(\sigma_t(p)) =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}
>  \frac{f(\sigma_t(p))-f(p)}{t} \end{align}

where $\sigma_t(p)$ is flow associated to $V$ such that $\sigma_0(p) = p$ and
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\sigma_t = V(\sigma_t).
\end{align}

From the above definition, one can show that

> \begin{align} \mathscr{L}_V f = V f \end{align}

since 
\begin{align}
(\mathscr{L}_V f)(p) = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(\sigma_t(p)) = df(p)[V(\sigma_0)] = df(p)[V(p)] = Vf(p).
\end{align}

Using the above fact, we have that

> \begin{align} \mathscr{L}_Y\mathscr{L}_X f = \mathscr{L}_Y[Xf]= YXf
>  \end{align}

since $Xf \in C^\infty(M)$. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
[\mathscr{L}_X\mathscr{L}_Y -\mathscr{L}_Y\mathscr{L}_X]\ f = XYf-YXf =[X, Y]\ f= \mathscr{L}_{[X, Y]}\ f.  
\end{align}